Is it on-topic to ask about mental state of celebrities?
There are celebrities who clearly have mental disorders, but there isn't anything about the matter in the internet. So is it allowed to ask about the mental state of a celebrity to find what their disease is?

No, we don't allow questions about individual people, and we don't do any sort of diagnosis, and we are not a gossip column.

what is the difference between questions about individual people and questions about a case study?

@Ooker A discussion of a case study would be a discussion about aspects of the reported case, not speculation about a named individual or substitution for a professional in case of someone seeking a self diagnosis. I find very little about them to be similar.

Sure. I think we would elaborate and emphasize this different so people can have a better sense on this
